# Error Code: 2014 Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, plsql

Como puedo resolver este error: **Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now.**

> #### ***El Procedimiento*** debe ***mostrar los primeros 5 apellidos y salario más altos***.

```
delimiter $$
    
    drop procedure if exists ejer8; //
    create procedure ejer8()
        begin
            declare Vfin int default 0;
            declare vApellido varchar(10);
            declare vSalario int;
            
            declare curEjer8 cursor for 
                select APELLIDO, SALARIO 
                from EMPLE
                order by SALARIO desc
                limit 5;
            declare continue handler for not found set Vfin=1;
            
            open curEjer8;
            
            bucle: loop
                fetch curEjer8 into vApellido, vSalario;
                if Vfin=1 then
                    leave bucle;
                end if;
            select "Apellido: ", vApellido, "Salario: ", vSalario;
            end loop;
            close curEjer8;
        end;
    $$
```

#### Tabla EMPLE

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya te lo he solucionado todo lo que he visto avísame si funciona @Rosa

Comment: He realizado los cambios que me ha sugerido y me sigue dando el mismo el error. No se a que pueda deberse.

Comment: Has copiado mi código tal cual? Porque si pinchas en el enlace de mi respuesta y lo ejecutas te saldrá @rosa  porque se me pasó el // que tiene que está mal y en el código está bien

Answer (score 0):

Resulta que estaba mal ya que  pusiste en el ***drop ;*** y es ***$$*** simplemente y un ***delimiter ;*** al final

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ejer8 $$
CREATE PROCEDURE ejer8()
BEGIN
    DECLARE Vfin INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE vApellido VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE vSalario INT;
    DECLARE curEjer8 CURSOR FOR SELECT APELLIDO, SALARIO FROM emple ORDER BY SALARIO DESC LIMIT 5;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET Vfin=1;       
    OPEN curEjer8;  
    bucle: loop
        FETCH curEjer8 INTO vApellido, vSalario;
        IF Vfin=1 THEN
            leave bucle;
        END IF;
        SELECT "Apellido: ", vApellido, "Salario: ", vSalario;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE curEjer8;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Lo llamo con ***call.***

```
CALL ejer8();
```

Y como resultado da esto :

| Apellido: | vApellido | Salario: | vSalario |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apellido: | Ochoa | Salario: | 55000 |

| Apellido: | vApellido | Salario: | vSalario |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apellido: | Sainz | Salario: | 43000 |

| Apellido: | vApellido | Salario: | vSalario |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apellido: | Campos | Salario: | 40000 |

| Apellido: | vApellido | Salario: | vSalario |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apellido: | Ojeda | Salario: | 38000 |

| Apellido: | vApellido | Salario: | vSalario |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apellido: | Perez | Salario: | 30000 |

---

***Nota :*** Yo tengo una estructura de tabla similar pero con otros datos.

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/331)